# graphql query versus generated swift query

Tags: ios, swift, aws-amplify

I am running this query:

```
query GetCommentWithPostAndComments {
  getComment( id: "a-comment-id-1" ) {
    id
    content
    post {
      id
      title
      comments {
        items {
          id
          content
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns this output? So this is a 1:m @connection

```
{
  "data": {
    "getComment": {
      "id": "a-comment-id-1",
      "content": "A comment #1",
      "post": {
        "id": "a-post-id",
        "title": "Post Title",
        "comments": {
          "items": [
            {
              "id": "a-comment-id-1",
              "content": "A comment #1"
            },
            {
              "id": "a-comment-id-2",
              "content": "A comment #2"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if I run the code generated in API.swift, I only get back a single comment:

```
let queryInput = GetCommentQuery(id: "a-comment-id-1")
appSyncClient?.fetch(query: queryInput, cachePolicy: .fetchIgnoringCacheData) { (result, error) in
       let json: JSONObject? = result?.data?.jsonObject
       let result = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json!, options: [])
}
```

So how can I translate the above query to return all comments?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the old iOS SDK (I'm not sure how it works on the new one), You may need to increase the depth of your auto-generated API.swift file. If you run amplify codegen configure, you can increase that depth to 2 or 3 to get those nested values returned as well. You can then run amplify codegen again and your API.swift file should include all of the nested info for your queries.

Warning, however, that as your schema gets more complex your API.swift file can get really huge with the additional nesting and it automatically generating all CRUD operations.

Another option is to create another file (call it "customqueries.graphql" or something) and place it in the graphql folder along with the queries.graphql, mutations.graphql, etc. In that file you can write custom queries and give them custom names, like:

```
query GetCommentWithPostAndCommentsCustom($id: ID!) {
  getComment( id: $id ) {
    id
    content
    post {
      id
      title
      comments {
        items {
          id
          content
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then you should have the autogenerated API.swift file include this Custom query, only returning the items you specified.